# CSV not exporting data from sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, ssis, export, export-to-csv

I have an issue exporting data from SQL query to csv file

All rows except '12107/E01' and photo.jpg data is not exporting to csv file

I am using SSIS package for exporting the data.

[image: Execution Log]

Any idea how can this be resolved?

Thanks,
Aruna

Comment: You should post your process log to get a good answer.  The first place I would look is at how many records are being returned from the query.

Comment: @JoeC Please see above

Comment: Are those the only two with special Characters? If you create a 2nd CSV, and route the "error data" to that one, do those to go through?